# generating list of strings varying by a certain amount of characters python

Tags: python, string

What is the best way to loop through a string and generate a list of all strings that vary from the original string by certain characters such as [ACGT]by  X(an integer less than the length of the string).

for example a character string `'AGT'` that varies by 2 characters:

```
"['AGCT']['AGCT']T", "A['AGCT']['AGCT']", "['AGCT']G['AGCT']"
```

Right now I am using a brute force method using a for loop to vary 1 character each loop. basically I need to run the loop and create a new list the amount of changes to a string I want; for example, if I wanted 2 changes I would need to run the loop 2 times and with each subsequent loop I would use the list from the previous loop.

```
sequences=['AGT','CGG']
l=[]
for sequence in sequences: 
    for i in range(len(sequence)):

        l.append( sequence[:i]+ 'C' +sequence[i+1:])
        l.append( sequence[:i]+ 'T' +sequence[i+1:])
        l.append( sequence[:i]+ 'G' +sequence[i+1:])
        l.append( sequence[:i]+ 'A' +sequence[i+1:])
new_lst=[]
for sequence in l: 
    for i in range(len(sequence)):

        new_lst.append( sequence[:i]+ 'C' +sequence[i+1:])
        new_lst.append( sequence[:i]+ 'T' +sequence[i+1:])
        new_lst.append( sequence[:i]+ 'G' +sequence[i+1:])
        new_lst.append( sequence[:i]+ 'A' +sequence[i+1:])
```

Comment: You can show us your working code and we can see if perhaps it can be improved.

Comment: Perhaps use a dynamic programming algorithm such as [Needleman–Wunsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)

Comment: You can not do much better than brute force, since the output size is exponential as well. You can not create a list of *k* elements, in less than *O(k)*.

Comment: I cant tell exactly but it sounds like you want `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Your strings look strange, what exactly are you showing there?

Comment: What exactly does "vary" mean?  Can extra characters be inserted?  If so, can they be inserted anywhere in the original string?  Can any character be inserted, or are we limited to a certain set of characters? (i.e. your example seems to only use the characters `AGCT`.)  Can characters already present in the original string simply be rearranged?  etc etc etc.

Comment: the strings in my above example was just regular expressions, so each of those characters in the string would be either an A,G,C or T. Also when I said vary I meant replacing x amount of characters in the string, not inserting or deleting characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't care about insertion of deletion of characters, only replacement.

There's no efficient way to do it as far as I know. It's an exponential problem. But `itertools` can help.

Let `s` be the string you are varying (e.g. 'AGT'). Let `variance` be the number of characters that differ (e.g. 2). Let `alphabet` be the list of allowed characters (e.g. 'ACGT').

First, you can loop through all of the combinations of indices that you may vary with `itertools.combinations(range(len(s)), r=variance)`. This gives you `(0, 1)`, `(0, 2)`, `(1, 2)`, etc.

Next, you need to figure out all the sets of replacement letters you can put in those positions. You can loop through the letters that differ with `itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=variance)`. This gives you tuples of length `variance` generated from your alphabet.

You probably want to make sure you replace letters in your string with new letters (e.g. you don't want to replace the first two letters in `'AGT'` with `'AG'`). So, you probably want to check that.

The following code puts the above together:

```
def replace(s, indices, replacement_letters):
    new_s = list(s)
    for (letter, idx) in zip(replacement_letters, indices):
        new_s[idx] = letter
    return ''.join(new_s)


def vary(s, variance, alphabet):
    # loop through the lists of positions that could differ in s
    for indices in itertools.combinations(range(len(s)), r=variance):
        # loop through lists of replacement letters for those positions
        for replacement_letters in \
                itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=variance):
            # check to make sure the replacement letters change s
            overlap = False
            for (letter, idx) in zip(replacement_letters, indices):
                if s[idx] == letter:
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if overlap:
                continue
            yield replace(s, indices, replacement_letters)


print(' '.join(vary('AGT', 2, 'GCAT')))
# GCT GAT GTT CCT CAT CTT TCT TAT TTT GGG GGC GGA CGG CGC CGA TGG TGC TGA ACG ACC ACA AAG AAC AAA ATG ATC ATA
```

Potential improvements: I'm pretty sure you can use different itertools methods to get rid of the extra step of checking to make sure the replacement letters all actually change the string. Anyways, I hope this serves as a good demonstration of the itertools methods that can help out in exponential blowup cases like this.